# App launches different activities

Tags: android

I have a Splash Activity which goes to login activity or home activity.
If the signed on is set to true, and now we are in the home activity.

Press home. Goto the app icon and open again. It shows the Splash Activity -> Home Activity.
Press home. In 15 secs, we close all the activities, then long press home, select the app in the list. It opens the login activity instead of going to Splash activity.

I am not sure why this is happening. Any suggestions where could I have gone wrong.

Comment: remove the Splash Activity so you are ok.

Comment: Code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your problem, you have the following hierarchy:

> SplashActivity -> [LoginActivity] -> HomeActivity

Where `LoginActivity` is optional.

If this is correct, you can simply add this code in the `onCreate()` - or even better on the `onResume()` (so it will be called when you go back to your activity) -  method of your `LoginActivity` class:

```
if (isAlreadyLogged) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Where `isAlreadyLogged` is a variable that you have to retrieve, for example from the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) of the phone.

This way, the LoginActivity will be directly skipped if the user is already logged in.

Comment: So you are telling to check both in SplashActivity and LoginActivity. I wonder why the SplashActivity is not getting called when I launch the app from the recent app list. It works grin when I goto the app icon and click on it.